# Bash script help with if then else and case sensitivity

Tags: bash, cron, if-statement, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Ok I'm trying to have a situation where I check if a file exists, if it does then I give the user the option to download it again - I want the default (enter) to be Y, I want Y or y to continue the script, I want N or n to exit the script, and I want all other responses to go back and re-prompt the question... but I'm stuck on that.

What I've done really just continues on (enter), and fails on all other responses other than lowercase y.

Here it is:

```
if [ -f $target/$remote_backup ];then
    read -p "This file already exists, do you still want to download? [Y/n]" decide
     if [ -z $decide ];then
        # if you press return it'll default to Y and continue
        decide="Y"
    else
        if [ $decide != y ]; then
        echo "Ok you said no or pressed a random button, exiting"
        exit -1
    fi
fi
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

The usual structure to use for this is `case`.

```
case "$decide" in
  y|Y|'') echo "yes" ;;
  n|N) echo "no" ;;
  *) echo "boo" ;;
esac
```

Comment: So that goes after the read? I won't be echoing I don't think, or do I need to in this situation? can i exit -1 if they press n and how can I loop if they answer * ?

Comment: Put it inside a loop. On N, `exit`. On Y, `break`.

Comment: Tell the user to enter a valid option.

Comment: I can't get that to ask the user to enter a valid option without kicking them off the script

Answer (score 1):

Try a `while` loop:

```
if [ -f $target/$remote_backup ]; then
    decide="?"
    while [ "$decide" != "y" -a "$decide" != "n" ]; do
        read -p "This file already exists, do you still want to download? [Y/n] " decide
        if [ -z $decide ]; then
            decide="y"
        fi
    done
    echo Decision: $decide
fi
```

Comment: I don't think I understand, does the while go in after? like this...
    if [ -f $target/$remote_backup ];then
    while [ "$decide" != "y" -a "$decide" != "n" ]; do
    read -p "This file already exists, do you still want to     download? [Y/n] " decide
    if [ -z $decide ]; then
        decide="y"
    fi
    done

Comment: @beatbreaker, the `while` goes after your first `if`. I updated my answer with more context.